# Error in mean(): argument is not numeric or logical

Tags: r

I got last 100 entries of the dataset, and stored them in a variable, then I tried to find mean of the variable. When I try to get mean of last 100 entries of dataset, I get the following error.

> Warning message: In mean. Default(last_100_entries): argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

```r
dat <- read.csv("Default.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
last_100_entries <- tail(dat, 100)
average_balance <- mean(last_100_entries)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to find the mean of an entire data frame. A data frame is a list of vectors, and `mean()` expects a single numeric or logical vector.

```r
biometrics <- 
data.frame(
  person    = c("jim", "kim", "hellen"), 
  weight_kg = c(70.8, 90.1, 83.4)
)

mean(biometrics)
#> Warning in mean.default(biometrics): argument is not numeric or logical:
#> returning NA
#> [1] NA
```

You can instead take the mean of a single column, like so:

```r
mean(biometrics$weight_kg)
#> [1] 81.43333
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can also attempt to get the `mean()` of every column of the data frame. There are a few ways of doing this:

```r
nums <- data.frame(
  num_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  num_2 = c(11, 12, 13),
  num_3 = c(50, 75, 158)
)

lapply(nums, mean)
#> $num_1
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $num_2
#> [1] 12
#> 
#> $num_3
#> [1] 94.33333

library(purrr)
map_df(nums, mean)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   num_1 num_2 num_3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2    12  94.3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: i want to get for a single column only, but for last 100 entries out of 10000